# .NET / Oracle: How to execute a script with DDL statements programmatically

Tags: c#, oracle, ddl

I want to do some programmatical schema manipulation against an oracle database in C#. Therefore, I struggle with some basic issues.

The ddl sql statements are located in a script file. I do not want to use sqlplus.exe, but I want to use OracleCommand out of the ODP.NET assemblies (System.Oracle.DataAccess). Here's an example of my script file:

script.sql:

```
DROP TABLE ABCDEF; 

DROP TABLE GHIJKL;
```

I want to point out:

- The script contains DDL statements (data definition language)
- The script contains **empty lines**
- The script contains **more than one statement**

The following code should execute my script:

```
var content = File.ReadAllText("script.sql");

using (var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
{
     oracleConnection.Open();

     using (var command = new OracleCommand(content) { Connection = oracleConnection })
     {
          command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

Executing this code, I do get an oracle error:

**Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00911: invalid character**

Maybe there is some issue with the formatting of the statements, I think. Any hint is appreciated. Thank you.

**---EDIT---**

To summarize my needs in a simple way: I search for an approach to execute any sql/ddl script, that is executable by SQL Plus, programmatically with C#.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried to wrap the script's content with "DECLARE BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '....' END;" as this should help with DDL statements, but no luck, same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Steve said, the semicolons are causing your error. And you can't wrap the entire file into a single `execute immediate` command, since that can only execute one statement at a time. You will need to parse your file and execute each command on its own, removing the semicolon that delinates commands. Your parsing will have to deal with string literals, as you noted, which in addition to containing semicolons may also contain doubled single quotes ('') within the single quotes (') that begin and end the string literal.

Answer (score 11):

Simply wrap it inside BEGIN and END and it will work smoothly

```
var content =string.Format("BEGIN {0} END;", File.ReadAllText("script.sql"));
using (var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))            
{
  oracleConnection.Open();
  using (var command = new OracleCommand(content) { Connection = oracleConnection })
  {
       command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Comment: couldn't you simply move those inside the SQL script ?

Comment: Sure you can, this is only for demonstration, though!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the **semicolon tip**!

My final code to run oracle scripts!

1) It accepts:
- empty lines / comment ( -- ) lines
- Multiline DDl / DML commands ending with ;

2) In case of error it throws an exception with the line number and sql command!

```
    public async Task ExecuteScript(string _connectionString, string script)
    {
        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(script))
        {
            var connection = new OracleConnection(_connectionString);
            connection.Open();

            string sqlCommand = "";
            string sqlLine; byte lineNum = 0;

            while ((sqlLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                sqlLine = sqlLine.Trim(); ++lineNum;

                if (sqlLine.Length > 0 && !sqlLine.StartsWith("--"))
                {
                     sqlCommand += (sqlCommand.Length > 0 ? Environment.NewLine : "") + sqlLine;  // Accept multiline SQL

                    if (sqlCommand.EndsWith(";"))
                    {
                        sqlCommand = sqlCommand.Substring(0, sqlCommand.Length - 1);

                        var command = new OracleCommand(sqlCommand, connection);

                        try
                        {
                            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(); 
                        }
                        catch (OracleException ex)
                        {
                            connection.Close();
                            var e2 = new Exception($"{lineNum} - {sqlCommand} <br/> {ex.Message}");
                            throw e2;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            connection.Close();

            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I will try to execute one line at time to see if you have any weird character that blocks the execution. (I am not sure also if you could send all of your commands  together on just one call).

Also you **should remove the semicolon** at the end of the lines

```
int lineNum = 0;
try
{
    string[] cmdTexts = File.ReadAllLines("script.sql");

    using (var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
    {
         oracleConnection.Open();
         OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
         command.Connection = oracleConnection;
         foreach(string cmd in cmdTexts)
         {
              lineNum++;
              if(cmd.Trim().Length > 0)
              {
                  if(cmd.EndsWith(";"))
                      cmd = cmd.Substring(0, cmd.Length - 1);

                  command.CommandText = cmd;
                  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
              }
         }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Exception on line: " + lineNum + " message: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem with this approach is that there might be semicolons contained in literals - that would break up long scripts.

Comment: So you are saying that you have a single script on multiple lines? Without a recognizable delimiter between scripts? Then you need to split in someway your inputs because I am pretty sure that the semicolon used as closure of a single command the cause of the error

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "single script on multiple lines". But I will have 'create table' statements that are longer than one line.
I finally need a mechanism to execute the same scripts that run with SQLPlus without problems.

Comment: If you have 'commands' that extends on more than one line and also text literals with semicolons inside the quotes, then the only possible solution is a parsing line by line to remove the semicolons at the end of the 'commands' but not the ones that are inside the text literals. Not an easy task and still you need to pass each 'command' separated. I have not an Oracle install to test but, before starting with parsing, I will try a simple file sql with just one command ending with semicolon and then without the semicolon just to check the difference with or without semicolon