# Running oracle commands script file inside C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have an application which has an oracle database, so the installation of the application needs running some oracle commands script files to create the database and perform some DDL operations.

I was trying to prepare an installation wizard using C# forms application. This wizard needs to run these commands. My questions are: Is C# windows forms app a good choice to achieve that? And how to perform it? i.e. how to run oracle commands script files from inside the application? I exactly need a function that takes the file path as input parameter and executes the commands within the script files...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would it not be just another class in your application?

Comment: This installation is the on the database server side, so there is no application to be installed here. Despite where is it located, I need to perform some oracle commands inside C# ?

Comment: I see this link: helpful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725379/net-oracle-how-to-execute-a-script-with-ddl-statements-programmatically

Comment: You could use ODBC (System.Data && System.Data.Odbc namespace) to connect (OdbcConnection) and execute (OdbcCommand) commands.